# libstlport_static.a: No such file: Permission denied

Tags: android, android-ndk

When compiling my android ndk project I have added

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

to my jni/Application.mk file which allows use of some STL stuff. however, when I clean and build I get an error
libstlport_static.a: No such file: Permission denied
I have found that a solution to this is to add

```
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true
```

This is a fix, but rebuilding the stlport library every time is obviously very time consuming. Is there a better fix to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't said which platform you are developing on, but I'm going to guess that it is Windows.

If you're using Vista or Windows 7, then the issue may genuinely be a permissions problem with the libstlport_static.a file. Either check the permissions on the file or try disabling User Account Control altogether.

Note that there are three versions of libstlport_static.a provided in the NDK. You should  be able to work out which one(s) your application is using by referring to the APP_ABI setting in your Application.mk file.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it was Windows 7. Turning off UAC worked perfectly! Unfortunately I can't vote-up your answer as I don't have enough rep yet :(

Comment: Hi
I had a similar problem when running on Windows.

I solved it by giving the .so files a full control permission

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing the permissions of the source file. In that case:

```
chmod 777 <ndk-dir>/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/libstlport_satic.a
```

Comment: In my case the issue was the stlport_static library has had weird permissions like so:

----------  1 bobby None   1040014 Mar  3 10:33  libstlport_static.a so I did chmod 755 on it and it worked to me too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NDK r7c, another way (instead of turning off UAC) is call `ndk-build` in Windows' command prompt (cmd) instead from bash under cygwin.

In NDK r7 and above, `ndk-build` is no longer dependent on cygwin and therefore invoking it directly in cmd avoids the permission issue because tools now have the same permission as you.  Note you still need cygwin if you want to debug your native code.